# CameraX Multiple Back Cameras

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I'm trying to implement a custom camera app using CameraX. Seeing as a lot of new devices have multiple back cameras now, I also want to include that. So basically, the user can select which camera to use. I've tried the following using the addCameraFilter option:

```
val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                    .requireLensFacing(when (camera.cameraSettings?.lensFacing?.let {
                        LensFacing.valueOf(it)
                    }) {
                        LensFacing.Back -> CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
                        else -> CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
                    })
                    .addCameraFilter { cameraList ->
                        val cameraChosen = camera.cameraSettings?.camera
                        cameraChosen?.let {
                            if (cameraChosen < cameraList.size) {
                                val setCamera = cameraList[cameraChosen]
                                cameraList.clear()
                                cameraList.add(setCamera)
                            }
                        }
                        cameraList
                    }
                    .build()
```

In debug mode, however, cameraList is always equal to 1. Even on devices with multiple back cameras. Does this mean that CameraX automatically chose the "right" camera? How can I manually choose another one (f.ex. some phones have a wide lens camera)?

Thanks!

Comment: If the device you're using has multiple back facing cameras but only 1 is provided in the camera filter, you might be facing something similar to [this](https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/c/Z6kCmARMKsQ), where the device has physical cameras that are not provided/returned in the public camera list (`getCameraIdList()`) but are parts of a logical camera, and are returned instead in [getPhysicalCameraIds()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#getPhysicalCameraIds()).

Comment: I've tested it on a Samsung A70 which has 3 back cameras. getCameraIdList() shows me 2 cameras (one of which is the front camera) and getPhysicalCameraIds() = 0

Comment: I also checked the link you provided and tried to implement the CameraFilter, but it doesn't return anything. Just a -lambda reference that doesn't work :/

Comment: The result you're seeing on the a70 is expected, if `getCameraIdList()` returns 1 back facing camera, then so will CameraX. On the link I provided in the previous comment, the last response provides an indirect way to get a specific physical camera by setting the zoom ratio. For instance, setting a zoom ratio smaller than 1 would give you access to the camera with the wide angle lens. It's not ideal, but the other option might be to use camera2 directly.